# JSON data binding issues with jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
var Jdata = [{"Store":480,"District":62,"Region":8,"Area":10,"City":"SPRINGFIELD","State":"TN","RiskClass":"RISK CLASS 2","AssignedDate":null,"AssignedBy":null,"AssignedConfig":null,"MatchCount":0,"MismatchCount":0,"ConfigModDate":null,"ConfigAppliedDate":null,"ConfigModBy":null},{"Store":590,"District":62,"Region":8,"Area":10,"City":"ASHLAND CITY","State":"TN","RiskClass":"RISK CLASS 0","AssignedDate":null,"AssignedBy":null,"AssignedConfig":null,"MatchCount":0,"MismatchCount":0,"ConfigModDate":null,"ConfigAppliedDate":null,"ConfigModBy":null}]

var tableCatValue = $('#AjaxGrid').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "pageLength": 5,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "data": Jdata,
                "columns": [

                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ">' + data.Store + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageDesc">' + data.District + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '53%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ct-ml-10">' + data.Region + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ct-ml-10">' + data.Area + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                }
                        ]
            });
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="AjaxGrid">  
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>
   <b>Group</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>Region</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>District</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>Store</b>
  </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem and question? Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: Data not loading into table.

Comment: And you probably have errors thrown in browser console... did you look?

Comment: @Dinesh has found out few issues even after those dosent work i would suggest you to check your json data https://jsonlint.com/ is a good site try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem1: First load `jquery` and then load `dataTable`.

Problem2: You have not included dataTable.css (To style table)

```js
var Jdata = [{"Store":480,"District":62,"Region":8,"Area":10,"City":"SPRINGFIELD","State":"TN","RiskClass":"RISK CLASS 2","AssignedDate":null,"AssignedBy":null,"AssignedConfig":null,"MatchCount":0,"MismatchCount":0,"ConfigModDate":null,"ConfigAppliedDate":null,"ConfigModBy":null},{"Store":590,"District":62,"Region":8,"Area":10,"City":"ASHLAND CITY","State":"TN","RiskClass":"RISK CLASS 0","AssignedDate":null,"AssignedBy":null,"AssignedConfig":null,"MatchCount":0,"MismatchCount":0,"ConfigModDate":null,"ConfigAppliedDate":null,"ConfigModBy":null}];

var tableCatValue = $('#AjaxGrid').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "pageLength": 5,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "data": Jdata,
                "columns": [

                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ">' + data.Store + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageDesc">' + data.District + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '53%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ct-ml-10">' + data.Region + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                },
                                    { data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '<div class=" messageName ct-ml-10">' + data.Area + '</div>';
                                    }, width: '20%'
                                }
                        ]
            });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   
<table id="AjaxGrid">  
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>
   <b>Group</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>Region</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>District</b>
  </th>
  <th>
   <b>Store</b>
  </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @vasanthnaidu please accept answer if it solved your problem

Comment: One more thing like, how to improve performance because we having 7000+ records.